# ubuntu bluetooth service status is running but bluetooth not working

Tags: bluetooth

Bluetooth service is active but when I go to Bluetooth setting it is not working:

[image: output]

Please give me a good solution.

[image: sudo lspci, sudo lsusb, and sudo rfkill]

Comment: Hello. Based on the info you have given here there is no solution. What version of Ubuntu are you running? How do you know it is active? What are you trying to use the Bluetooth for, what device? Are you getting any errors? Without some actual info can not even make a guess.

Comment: It will be impossible to offer any solution with the information provided. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) the Terminal output of `sudo lspci`, `sudo lsusb`, and `sudo rfkill`. Will this, it *may* be possible to offer a solution.

Comment: @matigo I just said most of that sheesh seems we were both typing same time just say time stamp. oh well

Comment: Pictures of text are not a good idea. Please cut and paste into the body of the question. Notice the whole right side is cut off in the picture.